# Angularjs API call to different action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am pretty new to AngularJs, so forgive me for not knowing this.
What I am trying to do:
I am trying to call an api with a different method name.
I have seen a lot about $resource,
however i don't understand it.

So the method I am trying to call:

```
        [Route("api/regions/{id?}"), Authorize]    
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Region> GetRegionsByStateId(Guid id)
        {
            var regions = _repository.Get();
            return regions.Where(x => x.StateId == id);
        }
```

I have tried `$http.get('api/regions/'+stateId)`
which doesnt work, can someone either explain the $resource a little better to me ot tell me why this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    [Route("api/regions/{id}"), Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Region> GetRegionsByStateId(Guid id)
    {
        var regions = _repository.Get();
        return regions.Where(x => x.StateId == id);
    }
```